# ReactJS: OnChange handler auto submitting data before onClick

Tags: reactjs

I'm still relatively new to React/Javascript & working with its functions.  I created a component that takes user input and renders a button that allows a user to link to an outside URL.
The button title is created by the user and then the URL is added.

However, when a url is pasted or I begin typing it, the onChange handler automatically creates the button without using the onSubmit function. So if I begin typing a paste a url (even if the data is wrong), the onChange event takes whatever I've input without allowing me to click "submit first".

I'm following this tutorial as a guideline for creating my onChange/onSubmit functions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qH4pJISKeoI&t=304s. His demo does not have the same issue and his input fields solve a different problem.

onChange & onSubmit Functions

```
    this.state = {
      links: [],
      url: '',
      title: ''
    }
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(e)
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  // onSubmit

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault(e)
  }

...

render() {
    if (this.state.url === '') {
      return (
        <>
          <form>
            <input
              name="title"
              type="text"
              placeholder="add button text"
              onChange={e => this.setState({ title: e.target.value })}
            />
            <input
              name="url"
              type="url"
              placholder="your-link.com"
              onClick={(e) => { e.stopPropagation() }}
              disabled={this.state.title === ''}
              onChange={e => this.setState({ url: e.target.value })}
            />
            <br />
          </form>
          <button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <div>
            <a href={this.state.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><p>{this.state.title}</p></a>
          </div >
        </>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried separating the onChange events using `onChange={this.title}` and `{this.url}` , disabling the URL field until the title is added, and adding `onClick={(e) => { e.stopPropagation() }}` in the url input field to prevent autosubmission as shown in the code above.

Any help understanding what causes this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's check what is happening:

1. We have onChange on input with `url`.
2. When anything is being changed in this input field,
3. On change is called and it triggers render method.
4. In render `if (this.state.url === '') {` this is no longer `true` so it creates link without needing to submit.

Answer (score 1):

Prevent default will not work while you have params in it:

```
e.preventDefault(e)
// probably this may be a typo instead?
// it's preventing you to go further line due to error.
```

Remove `e` param and it should be fine:

```
e.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input
            name="title"
            type="text"
            placeholder="add button text"
            onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
          />
          <input
            name="url"
            type="url"
            placholder="your-link.com"
            disabled={this.state.title === ''}
            onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
          />
          <br />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

do changes like this and check